# How to add Auto completion in vs code for Colors in flutter

Tags: flutter, vscode-extensions

I'm new to flutter and have been using android studio for the past 2 months. While transitioning to VS Code from android studio there are some unique features which I missed.

1. In Flutter whenever we need to add a color to a widget if we just type the [color] it'll auto complete it as Colors.[name of the color] which I used the most. But in VSCode I had to type till 'Colors.' to get the auto suggestion, is there a way to implement this feature in VSCode?
2. Is there a way to embed the emulator/simulator inside the VSCode?
   [AndroidStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYBeZ.png) [VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txrr6.png)

I searched for a few days and did not get any solution to this. So just wondering if anyone has found out a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Flutter and Dart extension on VScode to get those specific features, check them from this:

[Flutter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter)

[Dart](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.dart-code)